# Can't boot Ubuntu 18.04 with encrypted boot

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, encryption, luks

I've been using Ubuntu 18.04 with full disk encryption, lvm partitions and encrypted boot for months without any problem and now all of a sudden I am not able to boot using grub.

When I power on my computer the minimal grub bash is shown and I am able to boot with this manual procedure:

```
set prefix=/efi/ubuntu/
insmod luks
cryptomount (hdx,gpty)
set root=(lvm/system-root)/
linux (lvm/system-boot)/vmlinuz-[...]
initrd (lvm/system-boot)/initrd-[...]
insmod normal
normal
boot
```

Once booted I tried to reinstall grub with this command, after setting GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y in /etc/default/grub:

```
sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=ubuntu
```

After rebooting, the minimal bash prompt appears again and I have to repeat this procedure from scratch... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by booting using the above mentioned procedure and running [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) a couple of times. Black magic is always the solution!